# Is it faster to run straight to the windmill or to grab the speed buff first?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it faster to run from spawn to the windmill, or to run to the speed boost and then the windmill?

http://dominion.leagueoflegends.com/overview-dominion

Comment: Depends on champion, esp. those with blinks available at level 3.

Comment: It really doesn't, since you can blink to speed boost or top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The path with the speed boost is quicker.**

I tested this with my fiancee. We entered a custom game, chose the same character, and neither one of us purchased equipment. As such, our movement speeds were equal (320).

Then, we started at the very top corner of the stairs. This is the point your character naturally crosses when you go from the spawn to the top:

[image]

Green is actually slightly ahead since the two characters cannot occupy the same point. We put Green ahead to further illustrate the point.

At the same time, we ran to the top point. Green went around the speed boost (essentially not modifying the natural path that the champion takes when you click the top point), and red went through the speed boost (by way of manually guiding the champion across the speed boost plate). Red got their first with a little room to spare, even with the slight lead that Green had initially:

[image]

Comment: Damn thorough.  I think I'm going to have to test this myself, but the answer is what I suspected: it's always better to get the speed boost.

Comment: When you grab the speed boost you are also in the fog instead of telegraphing your move top to the entire enemy team.

Answer (score 2):

I just tested with 400 speed, going either way gave me 23 seconds, that's with no additional speed boosts. seems it's balanced in that way to not give an advantage.

without speed boost
L: 9:51:50
A: 9:52:13

With speed boost
L: 9:05:30
A: 9:05:53

Comment: Thanks.  That means it's better to get speed boost, since you get to keep it longer than just running to turret.

Comment: There is a difference. See [my answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31587/is-it-faster-to-run-straight-to-the-windmill-or-to-grab-the-speed-buff-first/31618#31618) for results at 320 speed.